# Are entry level programming positions usually unlisted?

Tags: job-search, entry-level, job-listing

Are entry level programming jobs not usually posted in job listings? Are they mainly acquired through word of mouth or by contacting the company directly?

Answer (score 4):

> Are entry level programming jobs not usually posted in job listings?

No, various universities and colleges may have listings for entry level positions for recent graduates. That is how I found my first programming job back in 1998.

> Are they mainly acquired through word of mouth or by contacting the
>   company directly?

No, they could also be acquired through a school's career services division or recruiters for a couple of other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

> Are entry level programming jobs not usually posted in job listings?
>   Are they mainly acquired through word of mouth or by contacting the
>   company directly?

No.

Many entry-level positions are often posted just like any other jobs. If you aren't seeing them, perhaps you just aren't looking in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases a few entry level positions are unlisted because they are for interns that have graduated. Of course the intern positions are listed on the company and university websites.

Unless the company is very small most have some way to post positions and accept resumes via the web. They may also advertise positions via sites like LinkedIn but these list generally ask you to apply via the website.

In many companies they may keep entry level positions advertised all the time. They know student complete their university studies at different times of the year and due to the different lead times needed for the positions it is just easier to constantly collect resumes, and then take the most recent ones as actual positions are needed.